# PHP error: open_basedir restriction in effect

Tags: php, require-once, open-basedir

I using this Yubico authentication PHP class: https://github.com/Yubico/php-yubico. I create php file test.php with this code:

```
<?php
 require_once 'Auth/Yubico.php';
 $otp = "ccbbddeertkrctjkkcglfndnlihhnvekchkcctif";

 # Generate a new id+key from https://api.yubico.com/get-api-key/
 $yubi = new Auth_Yubico('42', 'FOOBAR=');
 $auth = $yubi->verify($otp);
 if (PEAR::isError($auth)) {
    print "<p>Authentication failed: " . $auth->getMessage();
    print "<p>Debug output from server: " . $yubi->getLastResponse();
 } else {
    print "<p>You are authenticated!";
 }
?>
```

And do all instructions in this github library. When I open this script I get:

> Warning: require_once(): open_basedir restriction in effect.
>   File(/usr/share/php/Auth/Yubico.php) is not within the allowed
>   path(s): (/var/www/hmci/data:.) in
>   /var/www/hmci/data/www/hmci.ru/php-yubico/test.php on line 2 Warning:
>   require_once(/usr/share/php/Auth/Yubico.php): failed to open stream:
>   Operation not permitted in
>   /var/www/hmci/data/www/hmci.ru/php-yubico/test.php on line 2 Fatal
>   error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Auth/Yubico.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in
>   /var/www/hmci/data/www/hmci.ru/php-yubico/test.php on line 2

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`open_basedir` is a PHP option restricting PHP's access to specific directories.

You have the directory `/usr/share/php` in your include path without having access to it. Usually, PHP tries all paths in the `include_path` one by one. This means that PHP cannot find the file `Auth/Yubico.php` in the current directory, so PHP searches in `/usr/share/php` next.

Make sure that the file you want to include is actually there. You can also remove `/usr/share/php` from your include path  (either by editing the `php.ini` file, if you have access to it, otherwhise using the `ini_set()`method).

Comment: But what if this file in the /usr/share/php directory? I think that this class need PEAR and I install this library by PEAR. I think that this file in /usr/share/php.

Comment: You could also try adding `/usr/share/php` to your `open_basedir` configuration directive.

Answer (score 3):

Using an explicit path to the file you want to include causes PHP to skip the directory scanning causing the error:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Auth/Yubico.php';
```